# Track database table changes

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm trying to implement a way to track changes to a table named `user` and another named `report_to` Below are their definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` 
(
    `agent_eid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `agent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `agent_pipkin_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `hire_date` date NOT NULL,
    `active` bit(1) NOT NULL,
    `agent_id_req` bit(1) NOT NULL,
    `agent_eid_req` bit(1) NOT NULL,
    `agent_pipkin_req` bit(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`agent_eid`),
    UNIQUE KEY `agent_eid_UNIQUE` (`agent_eid`),
    UNIQUE KEY `agent_id_UNIQUE` (`agent_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `agent_pipkin_id_UNIQUE` (`agent_pipkin_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `report_to` 
(
    `agent_eid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `report_to_eid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`agent_eid`),
    UNIQUE KEY `agent_eid_UNIQUE` (`agent_eid`),
    KEY `report_to_report_fk_idx` (`report_to_eid`),
    CONSTRAINT `report_to_agent_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`agent_eid`) REFERENCES `user` (`agent_eid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `report_to_report_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`report_to_eid`) REFERENCES `user` (`agent_eid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

What can change that needs to be tracked is `user.team_id`, `user.active` and `report_to.report_to_eid`. What i currently have implemented is a table that is populated via an update trigger on `user` that tracks team changes. That table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_team_changes` 
(
   `agent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `date_changed` date NOT NULL,
   `old_team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `begin_date` date NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`agent_id`,`date_changed`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This works fine for just tracking team changes. I'm able to use joins and a union to populate a history view that tracks that change over time for the individual users. The issue of complexity rises when I try to implement tracking for the other two change types.

I have thought about creating additional tables similar to the one tracking changes for teams, but I worry about performance hits due to the joins that will be required.

Another way I have considered is creating a table similar to a view that I have that details the current user state (it joins all necessary user data together from 4 tables), then insert a record on update with a valid until date field added. My concern with that is the amount of space this could take.

We will be using the user change history quite a bit as we will be running YTD, MTD, PMTD and time interval reports with it on an almost daily basis.

Out of the two options I am considering, which would be the best for my given situation?

Comment: Approximately how many rows will you have in your tables when your system has been running for a year?

Comment: I would estimate apx 2000-2500 in `user` and `report_to`, with roughly 7000 total changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options you've presented:

1. using triggers to populate transaction-log tables.
2. including a new table with an effective-date columns in the schema and tracking change by inserting new rows.

Either one of these will work. You can add logging triggers to other tables without causing any trouble.

What distinguishes these two choices?  The first one is straightforward, once you get your triggers debugged.

The second choice seems to me that it will create denormalized redundant data. That is never good. I would opt not to do that.  It is possible with judicious combinations of views and effective-date columns to create history tables that are viewable as the present state of the system. To learn about this look at Prof. RT Snodgrass's excellent book on Developing Time Oriented applications. http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/publications.html  If you have time to do an excellent engineering (over-engineering?) job on this project you might consider this approach.

The data volume you've mentioned will not cause intractable performance problems on any modern server hardware platform. If you do get slowdowns on JOIN operations, it's almost certain that the addition of appropriate indexes will completely fix them, as long as you declare all your `DATE`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP` fields `NOT NULL`. (`NULL` values can mess up indexing and searching).

Hope this helps.